# Property doesn't exist on type 'object' when using optional chaining

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, optional-chaining

There is no way that [this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAKEAjAVgLhprAU2CgEpkA+fbAfgDoAHAJxAYG4g) fails

```
const fn = (obj: object) => obj?.prop;
```

but the TypeScript compiler prevents me from writing that, explaining that

> Property 'prop' does not exist on type 'object'

but that's precisely the use of optional chaining: if the property exists, I access it, else I access undefined, and it works on any `object`. So why does TS doesn't let me write this and is there a setting in my `tsconfig.json` I can set so that I can write that?

Comment: That's not what optional chaining is. Optional chaining checks if `obj` is null, not if the property to the right exists (`prop`).

Comment: Well yeah but that won't ever make the code fail because `({}).prop` is valid JS that doesn't throw a `TypeError`

Comment: There are many things that are valid in JS that are unacceptable in TS; that is very intentional. If all you want is type-hinting, you might check out JS docs instead (e.g., [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking)). It's a nice balance of familiar JS with better IntelliSense and no additional compiling.

Answer (score 1):

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

> The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

In your case, `obj` is the reference being checked for `null` or `undefined`, **not** `prop`.

---

> So why does TS doesn't let me write this

You've told TS to expect an `object`, but you have not told TS anything about the properties of that object, so it has no idea if `prop` exists. In other words, `prop` is not on the interface of `object`, so it throws a compiler error.

---

> is there a setting in my tsconfig.json I can set so that I can write that?

The behavior from above is the whole point of TypeScript, a static type checker. *You do not want this exact behavior to be enabled*, but there is an intended way within the language to produce the same effect:

```js
const fn2 = (obj: Record<string, any>) => obj.prop;
```

The above code requires that `obj` be non-null/undefined and allows for any `string` (or `number`, but not `Symbol`) property accessor.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcHtNA7BDAToyB3AsAKAMaVgZ3FADNZQBeUACkgCMArALlDvoFNtwBKCgPhYYA6AA4phAbixYQoAIKgA3qAC+oVAEtwAC1DxYATzgBXALa02iFsVCjIwi+HVt8V3QYj77WXASKkATBTUrMwAShyQiAAmADyEiOqwAOYANG76vDzk-KwiYpKYAVRKtsLMAOTE0OVptEgVdQBe5SpcWEXl2uouGgA2vaAAcgDyACpqkQDW5TwyAMJ6sJBE8NjYbMIroPGJSWpabGTwiqAA2qXMO8kAusx6hqrdoGwAHvacbFFSmDKyBl3JahRbrwWi9NgeewAWmwB2wk12LDIrF0vSgSTY2gsbRweEIJFgAGYgjQGHcDFkckJSgVSITijYxBUqpAaqA6ogGvBmq12kSqJ0tE8+gNUFMZkA)